# Spark DataFrame to ADW table: unable to insert column with chars >4k

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I have spark dataframe, on DataBricks, with a column with value having character length > 10,000.

I need to insert this into Azure Data Warehouse (ADW) table but I get an error if the column char length is above 4,000.

> Error: Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: HadoopSqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.

```
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
.option("url", sqlDwUrl) \
.option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
.option("dbtable", writeTableName) \
.option("tempDir", tempDir) \
.mode("append") \
.option("maxStrLength",4000)\
.save()
```

What do i need to do to insert my column with character length > 10k or 20k.

Answer (score 0):

When we look into the capacity limits of SQL Data Warehouse  today

```
Bytes per Column - (depends on the column data type)
Limit is 8000 for char data types, 
4000 for nvarchar, or 2 GB for MAX data types.
```

So it is not possible for us to ingest a column of character length > 10k today. The option may be to split the column data to ingest and later merge the columns if required to.